# Unable to view trusted domains in ADUC

Tags: active-directory

My domain is Server 2003 (domainA) and the remote domain is Server 2008R2 (domain functional level) (domainB). At some point in the recent past, I lost the ability to view domainB (ADUC -> open a group -> add member -> click the Location button). When I follow those steps now, I only see my local domain (domainA).

I have verified the following:

- Two-way trust
- Validate button in ADDT doesn't report any issues
- dcdiag shows all passed, except for the events (which appear unrelated)
- repadmin /replsummary shows 0 fails
- I can ping the domain FQDNs (domain.local) and get back the IP of a DC in the other domain
- If I click the "Location" button in domainB, I can see both the domains

We recently made two changes to domainA. First, we updated the schema for an impending Exchange upgrade. Second, we introduced our first Server 2012R2 DC (before, we had up to 2008R2). Since I do not know when the visibility into domainB broke, I do not know if it happened before or after either of these changes.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sites showing in AD Sites and Services? Checked there?

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. How would I see the OU structure of a remote domain in ADSS? I can only see the replication topology of the local domain with that tool.